# Which is correct about primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql

It's been a while when I work with databases that's why I need some advice about what I'm doing and thinking. Lately I've been involve with a project that a **primary keys** would be a custom generated.  This is the set up in supply table **supply id** should be a varchar why? They wanted to know when it is purchase sample:

supply table

> supply id: ( **sup-4/23/2017-123456** ) Explanation *sup* **for supply** *2/23/2017* **for the current date** *123456* **random 6 digits**

property table

> property id ( **123456-123456-123456** ) Explanation ***first 6 digits*** general ID from the accounting system, **second 6 digits** specific id based on general id, **third 6 digits** random 6 digits.

What did I think:

> I will create an ID primary key with varchar datatype look at the **first image**
>   [image: id with varchar datatype]
>
> I create supply_id primary key int and I created another supply_code varchar datatype look at the **second image**

[image: supply_id supply_code]

I need some advise for what is right between the two. I'm thinking that there would be a problem in each of my solution. I'm always thinking to use a standard primary like using INT now with a custom primary key.

Comment: Your _primary key_ should be a simple int with auto increment. For your _special_ key, you could use multiple columns, and add a unique index to prevent duplicates. Generally speaking, it is bad practice to use data values to create a primary key since those values might be edited at some point. A primary key should be independent of data values so it never changes once created. IOW, it is used to identify a specific row in the table regardless of the data values.

Comment: @SloanThrasher, that what I'm really thinking Sir, **INT** for the primary keys but they wanted to add the **DATES* in every purchase as an **ID**.

Comment: The difference is just terminology. A primary key is a specific entity. What you want is a unique key in addition to the primary key. You could use a trigger (insert and update triggers) to maintain it.

Comment: @SloanThrasher. I'll go for the triggers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't use anything meaningful for a primary key. As soon as it needs to have a certain meaning, put it in a separate column, but do not make it your primary key. If you really want you can still put a unique constraint on that other column.

Comment: @trincot, Sir thanks for the help.